# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE trim out £

Tags: mysql

I'm dumping a csv file into a mysql table, and I've managed to wrangle the niggles out of all the fields, except one. The csv file stores the value as £x.xx, and I need it as x.xx

My code is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.ext'
            INTO table TABLENAME
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'   
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
            IGNORE 7 LINES
            (@billValue)
            SET 
            billValue  = REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(@billValue), '£', ''), ',',''),
            ;
```

I've also tried

```
 TRIM(LEADING '£' FROM NULLIF(@billValue, '')),
```

but it's not sticking. I've been getting

```
Incorrect decimal value: 'Â£0.00' for column 'billValue'
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What encoding are you using?

Comment: That was it! UTF-8 messing things up. I resaved it non UTF-8 and it worked fine.  

I did get a warning for each line

Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns 


My actual csv has more than just the field I mentioned above, if I'm still getting the input I want, it's okay to ignore this?

Answer (score 1):

As Álvaro González had hinted at, my CSV was UTF-8 encoded, and was causing issues. The problem after that was resolved when I realised there were three extra columns at the end of each row. By assigning them to user variable and not assigning the variable to a table column, they're discarded. Hope this helps anyone else.

Thank you Álvaro